# Are there any mountain towns or villages near Osaka with cooler weather than Osaka itself (5-10 degrees C cooler)?

Tags: japan, weather-and-climate, mountains, osaka

I am going to Osaka soon and the weather is hot now.

Are there any mountain towns or villages nearby with cooler weather by 5 or 10 degrees or so?

I know about Mount Kongo already but I don't know much about it.

A short list of mountain towns or villages that fit the bill would be nice if anyone has this information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is "near" in your book, but any mountainous area will be cooler and less muggy than the coastal lowlands.  Some tourist favorites are **Mount Koya** (高野山), a famous pilgrimage site for Shingon Buddhists which has a lot of temple accommodation and is 2-3 hours away from Osaka, and the hills/mountains above Kobe, which are full of hot springs like **Arima Onsen** (有馬温泉), the closest of which are only an hour and a bit away.  10 degrees cooler is going to be hard unless you go all the way to the Japan Alps around Gifu/Nagano though.